# Are there any COGO tools in QGIS 1.9+?

Tags: qgis, cogo

The "Azimuth and Distance" plugin does not appear to be maintained any longer, and has not been transitioned to the new QGIS 2.0 plugin repository. What are the current options for entering COGO in QGIS? Does the roadmap include these tools, or is this something that will still depend on a plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azimuth and Distance has since been ported to QGIS 2.0. The version of the plugin you need is [0.9.0 or later](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAzimuth/version/0.9.0/).

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck using the [m.cogo](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/m.cogo.html) tool in GRASS.  It's a clunky work around because it just takes in input of properly formatted COGO calls and outputs a series of coordinates.  You have to play "connect the dots" in order to get the shape you were trying to COGO, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I've played with m.cogo in GRASS, and it's a bit 'clunky' for our needs. I need something that is quick and has a minimum of steps in order to roll out to a 'production' environment. m.cogo would work if it was a less frequently used task, but alas it's something we do often.